# How to enable 'daw' vi command in zsh?

Tags: zsh, vi

I've seen that the vi mode option in zsh is rather limited.

For example, 'daw' (delete around word) and 'diw' don't work.

What is the reason and how can I solve it?

Comment: Because it's a `vi` mode, not a `vim` mode. `daw`, `diw` are vim-only and are not the most useful ones. You can do the same with `bdw`, `bde`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Doh! I've always used vim. Is there an option to use vim mode (guess not)?

Answer (score 4):

> Because it's a `vi` mode, not a `vim` mode. `daw`, `diw` are vim-only and are not the most useful ones. You can do the same with `bdw`, `bde` –  Stephane Chazelas

That being said you can use `bindkey -s` to bind one string to another:

```
bindkey -a -s "diw" "bde"
bindkey -a -s "daw" "bdw"
```

Now when you type `diw` `bde` is sent back.

`-a` is needed to add the binding to the `vicmd` mode.

#### Update for *zsh* version ≥ 5.0.8

Since version 5.0.8 *zsh* also supports vim style text objects. So `daw` and `diw` should work out of the box.